NVMe speed too low?
I got 52Pi M.2 NVME SSD Adapter N04 for my raspberry pi 5. I connected NVMe SDD and booted from it. It works, but it's very sluggish. This is how it looks like
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           805M  6.3M  799M   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2  458G  4.7G  431G   2% /
tmpfs           4.0G  608K  4.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M   48K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p1  510M   75M  436M  15% /boot/firmware
tmpfs           805M  144K  805M   1% /run/user/1000

sudo hdparm -t --direct /dev/nvme0n1p2

/dev/nvme0n1p2:
 Timing O_DIRECT disk reads:  96 MB in  3.00 seconds =  31.98 MB/sec


Usually I'm getting like 600KB/sec here (this is first time I got 30MB).
And also getting some warnings here
sudo journalctl -f
Apr 29 19:05:12 raspberrypi kernel: nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x0
Apr 29 19:05:12 raspberrypi kernel: nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x0
Apr 29 19:05:12 raspberrypi kernel: nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x0
Apr 29 19:06:19 raspberrypi sudo[1955]:       pi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/pi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/hdparm -t --direct /dev/nvme0n1p2
Apr 29 19:06:19 raspberrypi sudo[1955]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by pi(uid=1000)
Apr 29 19:06:25 raspberrypi sudo[1955]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Apr 29 19:08:07 raspberrypi kernel: nvme nvme0: I/O 769 (I/O Cmd) QID 4 timeout, aborting
Apr 29 19:08:09 raspberrypi kernel: nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x0
Apr 29 19:08:09 raspberrypi sudo[1962]:       pi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/pi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl -f
Apr 29 19:08:09 raspberrypi sudo[1962]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by pi(uid=1000)


journalctl -b | grep pcieport
Apr 29 19:02:31 raspberrypi kernel: pcieport 0000:00:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Apr 29 19:02:31 raspberrypi kernel: pcieport 0000:00:00.0: PME: Signaling with IRQ 38
Apr 29 19:02:31 raspberrypi kernel: pcieport 0000:00:00.0: AER: enabled with IRQ 38
Apr 29 19:02:31 raspberrypi kernel: pcieport 0001:00:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Apr 29 19:02:31 raspberrypi kernel: pcieport 0001:00:00.0: PME: Signaling with IRQ 44
Apr 29 19:02:31 raspberrypi kernel: pcieport 0001:00:00.0: AER: enabled with IRQ 44


In sudo nano /boot/firmware/config.txt added dtparam=pciex1
Were could be the problem?
UPDATE
I tried to check the speed a few times now. Here are the data.
sudo hdparm -t --direct /dev/nvme0n1p2

/dev/nvme0n1p2:
 Timing O_DIRECT disk reads: 1292 MB in  3.00 seconds = 430.08 MB/sec
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo hdparm -t --direct /dev/nvme0n1p2

/dev/nvme0n1p2:
 Timing O_DIRECT disk reads:  54 MB in  3.00 seconds =  17.99 MB/sec
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo hdparm -t --direct /dev/nvme0n1p2

/dev/nvme0n1p2:
 Timing O_DIRECT disk reads:   2 MB in  3.58 seconds = 572.52 kB/sec



NVMe SSDs can get hot during operation, which can lead to performance throttling.

thanks for your comment! I think in my case it wasn't caused by heat. Because I tried it straight after boot. Also I found at some forum that geekworm NVMe HAT has problems with NVMe SSD that use some kind of a chip (idk name). So maybe this was the cause...
